# IE9 res://ieframe.dll Error

Tags: html, facebook, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a website that allows users to post images to Facebook pages. Im using a form and posting it to a hidden IFRAME, to prevent the user from being redirected after the images was posted.

The form definition:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="getAction(this);" target="uploader">
//....form code....//
```

The Iframe:

```
<iframe name="uploader" width=2px height=2px style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

My problem is, that in **My Own** Internet Explorer 9, When I'm trying to upload an image, Im getting these errors:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/noConnect.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/down.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg
```

And it gets even weirder, as in my friend's computer, which has the same IE9 version, and is connected to the same network, the post is working just fine (It is also working on another computer in my house, and another one in my brother's computer). **I could have said that it is only a local problem, but as this site addresses many clients, I cant afford not understanding this error, if it happened on my own OS, it can happen on other machines.**

I will also note that this is **working on Chrome and FireFox with no problem**.

I'm not sure that it is a code related issue, I've tried to google it and found both [Microsoft Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2601307/en-us?sd=rss&spid=15672) and [This article](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/ieframedll.htm). But I removed any third party IE addons, We and my friends are connected to the same router (So it is not a router issue) and I've installed the latest Windows Updates.

I'm currently have no idea about solving the problem, So I wanted to ask if any of you have experienced similar/same errors ? and maybe has some ideas about solutions...

I will be happy to provide more code if requested, but I didn't want to fill the question with code from the first place, as in most scenarios it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is working in your friend’s IE 9, but not in your’s – then *compare your security settings*.

Especially the one named *“Launching programs and files in an IFRAME”* could be the deal breaker, I’d suspect.

If that one is not it, then try to set every security option offering this from “Disable” to “Prompt”, and see if you get any messages in your IE.

Comment: As developers we should not expect our users to make any changes in their Browser settings. This is a security feature that is enabled on the backend (or proxy) and is there for a reason I guess. It has to be fixed on the backend in the security headers.

Answer (score 11):

It is best to fix this problem at **server** level rather than **client** side, since we can't expect all other site visitors to change their IE settings just so they can use your website.

As you mentioned, it is indeed caused by your iframe in **https** environment. **IE9** is particular strict on this, so you will need to define it in your x-frame-options:

### For Apache, HTTP Server

Add/Change following line in Apache Web Server’s httpd.conf file

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Make sure it is not set to `DENY`.
Restart web server

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I believe this setting is to control if your pages are allowed to be embedded on other sites or not in frames and iframes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

We had these exact errors in the IE11 console yesterday. 
For us, setting the Request Header in IIS for the iframed content (the page that will be the src of the iframe) to P3P=NOI helped. We got there by checking on Request Headers based on Georges answer above.

The scenario was different in the way that we were passing an number generated by the portal to the iframed content by query parameter. Both the portal and the iframed site run https.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by the site I was connecting to not having a valid HTTPS certificate.  I'd created one for development that Windows did not recognise as being a trusted certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@George Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23286597/2950458), we are able to pinpoint the issue -

We recently faced this issue when we enabled spring security in our project. After knowing the issue is due to the X-Frame-Options=DENY (Got as response headers in developers tools), we realized that spring security by default appends headers with default values -

[Security Headers](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html)

Removing it fixed our issue -

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      // ...
      .headers().disable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution for 'res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm#':
1. Open Control Panel-Internet Options
2. Privacy tab
3. Set Low 
4. Apply and OK.